# Proof for an equivalence of inverse functions when range of one function contains entire image set of other

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Munkres in his Topology book says

Let $f : X \to Y$ be continuous. If $f(X) \subset Z \subset Y$ , we show that the function $g : X \to Z$ obtained from $f$ is continuous. Let $B$ be open in $Z$. Then $B = Z \cap U$ for some open set $U$ of $Y$.

**Because $Z$ contains the entire image set $f (X)$, $f^{−1}(U)$ = $g^{−1}(B)$, by elementary set theory.**

How does the last equation follow from set theory?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the equality $f^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}(B)$ by proving that $$x\in f^{-1}(U)\iff x\in g^{-1}(B)$$for arbitrary $x\in X$.

That can be interpreted as an application of elementary set theory.

---

**Edit** (to make things more clear).

For a fixed $x\in X$ the following statements are equivalent:

- $x\in f^{-1}(U)$
- $f(x)\in U$
- $f(x)\in B=Z\cap U$ (this because $f(X)\subseteq Z$ so that $f(x)\in Z$
- $g(x)\in B$ (this because $g(y)=f(y)$ for every $y\in X$, also for the fixed $x$)
- $x\in g^{-1}(B)$

Comment: I am trying to proceed as follows. Let x∈$f^{−1}&(U). Since the image of f is contained in Z and U is contained in image of f we can conclude B = U.  Now, since g is an entirely different function i am not able to figure out a way to conclude that x∈$g^{−1}&(U).  Same concern for going the other way around since f here is an entirely different function, i cannot conclude that if x∈$g^{−1}&(U) it implies x∈$f^{−1}&(U).

Comment: I have added something to my answer.

Comment: The domain of both g and f is X.  if  g(y)=f(y) for every y∈X, how are they different. What is the impact then of having a different range for g and f?

Comment: @STEMExchanger If functions are only looked at as sets of ordered pairs then there is no difference between $f$ and $g$. But often functions are looked at as triples $f=(X,G,Y)$ where $X$ is the domain, $Y$ the codomain and $G$ the graphs (i.e. the set $\{(x,f(x)\mid x\in X\}$). Then here $g=(X,G,Z)$ with $Z\neq Y$ hence $g\neq f$. The impact concerns for a great deal the possibility of composition. If e.g. $h$ is another function with domain $Z$ then the composition $h\circ g$ exists, but the composition $f\circ h$ does not exist.

Comment: Consider the elements of the set Z\f(x), is it correct to state then that this set could be nonempty, that for this set, there cannot be preimage in f. (Not onto) Since the range of g is called a restriction, in fact, there could be an even bigger set Y\f(x) that does not have a preimage in f.  If this is the case, why not just say the co domain is the set f(x) instead of having a set Y that is the co domain which is bigger than f(X)?   What is the need/applications of such a definition?

Comment: Thanks for your patience through my efforts to understand this.  Also, it sounds odd that even though the co domain for g, Z,  is potentially only larger than possible elements of the range f(x),  g is called a restriction....

Comment: On your last comment: we have $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Z$ where $Z\subseteq Y$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ for each $x\in X$. This justifies the term "restriction".

Comment: The set $Z\setminus f(X)$ can be non-empty, but that does not affect the existence of a preimage under $f$ or $g$). If $A\subseteq Z\setminus f(X)$ then $f^{-1}(A)=\varnothing=g^{-1}(A)$. I stop here. You will have to get used to codomains larger than ranges and determining for a function. On this site you might find questions about it with answers.

Comment: I am comfortable with codomains larger than the range in general, only in this particular context of constructing new continuous function where f(x) = g(x) everywhere and If A⊆Z∖f(X) then $f^{-1}(A)=∅=g^{-1}(A) the construction strikes me a bit vacuous